Select objects by list id
How can I query a list of objects by list Id in @vercel/postgres?
I tried:
const dataOTP = await sql<OTP>`
      SELECT *
      FROM otps
      WHERE id IN (${listOTPId.join(", ")})
    `;

But it got 22P02 ERROR.
When I tried another way like this, it worked correctly:
const dataOTP = await sql<OTP>`
      SELECT *
      FROM otps
      WHERE id IN (${listOTPId[0]}, ${listOTPId[1]})
    `;

Can someone tell me why?

In this type of problem, here is how you should approach it:


Make everything static first (remove the variables). E.g: SELECT (...) WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)


Then check if it works. If it does, check the output of your variables. E.g: does listOTPId.join(", ") matches the above?



Thanks for your advise.
When I use listOTPId.join(", "), I tried to log the result of query string and I got the same result with static string.
So do you think we have another type or vercel/postgres library problem here?

Unlikely. Either way, try to build a 'minimal reproducible example'.
Is this list holding integers? If so, the issue may be in the difference between [1,2,3].join(", ") and ([1,2,3][0], [1,2,3][1]. The first outputs a string, while the second will output 2 integers. Those two types may behave differently in the sql`` expression. Try to reproduce with listOTPId[0].toString() if that is the case.

That's it. It is a different between string type and integer type in sql`` expression, that prevent me to make a dynamic query. And do we have the solution for this problem?

You can use "client.query" instead to generate dynamic queries. I had the same exact issue trying to call a "WHERE id in (${string_of_ids})" type query. Solved it by doing the following:
Instead of this:
const data = await sql`
    SELECT *
    FROM albums
    WHERE id IN (${ids_string})`

I did this:
const client = await db.connect();
const data = await client.query(`
    SELECT *
    FROM albums
    WHERE id IN (${ids_string})`)

That got around the parameterized queries issue. In my case, I kept having an error because the parameter was supposed to be an integer, but I was passing in a string of integers as the parameter.

Assuming "vercel" (never heard of it) can properly construct an array, then ANY is a better choice than the syntactic-construct of IN.
richard=> SELECT 1 = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

richard=> SELECT 4 = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
├──────────┤
│ f        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

